# Displaying a bootstrap modal in PHP without using a trigger button

Tags: php, jquery, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-modal

I want to display a modal by checking if a PHP session exists, the following is the code :

```
<?php if(isset($_SESSION['login'])) { ?>
    <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
    <div class="modal-header">
    <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
    <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-body">
    <p>Body</p>
    </div>
    <div class="modal-footer">
    <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
    <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
    </div>
    </div>
    <script>$("#myModal").modal("show");</script>
<?php } ?>
```

This is not working.

I have also referred previous similar questions but they do not give a clear picture.Please help.

Comment: maybe session is not set?

Comment: I have checked putting an echo statement within the if statement .It is set

Comment: include js and all relevant code :)

Comment: Does removing the if statement show the modal?

Comment: @ahb Yes it does, but the screen becomes dim and no texts are displayed other than the bg

Comment: @ahb It worked on a big screen once i removed the hide class but the texts and the button isn't visible on a small screen

Comment: @bargad, either use bootstrap 2.xx lib with your current Modal HTML or Update the Modal HTML to boostrap 3.xx, the problem will be resolved (problem is that you are using latest bootstrap framework lib with old modal HTML structure)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, I would suggest to separate the `.js` file from the `.php`
Because -sometimes- I also need to run php code in my js files, this is a little "trick" that I like to do:

The js file, should have extension `.php` (in order to trigger the php interpreter) and thus the filename could look something like that: `scripts.js.php`. Here I also assume that you have your main file called for example: `index.php`.

Now, let's bake the cake:

Sample of the `index.php` file:

```
<html>
<head>
    <!-- here include your head elements and styling -->
    <link href="path/to/bootstrap.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link href="path/to/other.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>
<!-- here goes the body code -->
    <!-- my practice is to include the modal code and scripts at the end of the file -->
        <div id="myModal" class="modal hide fade" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel" aria-hidden="true">
        <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">×</button>
        <h3 id="myModalLabel">Modal header</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Body</p>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn" data-dismiss="modal" aria-hidden="true">Close</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
        </div>
        </div>

    <?php 
        $show_modal="";
        if(isset($_SESSION["login"])){$show_modal="1";}else{$show_modal="0";}
        include("scripts.js.php"); 
    ?>
    </body>
    </html>
```

And here is my suggestion for the scripts.js.php file:

```
<script src="path/to/jquery.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/bootstrap.js"></script>
<script src="path/to/otherfile.js"></script>
<script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    var showModal = '<?php echo $show_modal; ?>';
    if(showModal=="1"){$("#myModal").modal("show");}
});
</script>
```

This is a solution that always work for me... Hope it works for you too!